# Can interrogative who be substituted by whom?

Tags: interrogatives

> **Who** are the letters for? (James Joyce, Ulysses)

It seems that ***who*** is moved forward to make an interrogative sentence, from after *for*. Then can you use *whom* instead of *who*, for the latter would be ‘whom’ when it comes after ‘for’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's an extracted object of the preposition *for*, with the preposition stranded.  It's standard to use *who*, but *whom* is acceptable in this position.  If you do use it, it makes the sentence more old-fashioned or formal-sounding.  It can also be perceived as emphatic; this is because *who* is the usual choice, so *whom* draws attention to itself.

For more information about the historical distinction between *who* and *whom*, and to learn how it has changed over time, I suggest reading [this Language Log post by Arnold Zwicky](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004084.html).